# Element not being updated with new HTML, with element onMouseEnter, React.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Really simple problem where when I hover over the navigation bar of my page (in a unordered list), the tab is supposed to update with a new value. The value updates, but the attributing HTML markup does not render along with it (such as when I tried to make the 'why' value bold. I tried even storing both of the values in two variables and concat together, but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot of Nav Bar (Vertical):
  [image]

My Default Props:

```
 getDefaultProps: function(){
  var text = '<i className="fa fa-laptop"></i>';
  var text2 = '<b>why<b>';
  return{why: text + text2};
},
```

Line needing to be changed:

```
<li value = '3' className = "nav-content" style = {ulTop} onMouseEnter = {this.change} onMouseLeave = {this.out} ref = 'whyTab'><Link to = '/Why'><i className="fa fa-code"></i>{this.props.why}</Link></li>
```

Comment: Missing some relevant code, but getDefaultProps is only called ONCE -- when the component is constructed.  You probably meant to put that logic in the render function, instead.

Comment: Hey, yes I'm aware, I just didn't want to post everything that my component is doing to cut down on confusion. Instead I posted just the default props to show that even at first render of the page, the code wasn't changing the element how I wanted. But I figured out why, it's because it's assigning the HTML as plain text values, rather than markup. Had to call on the Ref and do a innerHTML attribute to get it to treat the text as markup

Comment: Nice, you should add an answer to your own question for future visitors

Comment: Yes I'm going to when I get back to the office :-) , on mobile at the moment